# Como fazer uma expressão regular para validar senha JSF

Tags: java, jsf

Preciso de uma expressão regular para validar senha conforme abaixo:

A senha precisa ser no padrão: ipe@1234 (letras, caracteres especiais e números)

Estou usando essa abaixo, só que não valida, da erro:

```
<p:password id="passwordInput" class="password" size="35"
maxlength="20" value="#{funcionarioBean.novaSenha}"
required="true" validatorMessage="Senha válida somente no padrão ipe@1234.">
<f:validateRegex pattern="((?=.\\d)(?=.[a-z])(?=.[A-Z])(?=.[@#$%]).{6,20})"/>
</p:password>
```

Sempre aparece a mensagem "Senha válida somente no padrão ipe@1234", mesmo usando a senha ipe@1234.

---

Esse é o xhtml que estou usando para fazer a validação:

```
<ui:define name="conteudo">
        <p:growl id="frmLoginGeral" />
        <div id="redefinir">
            <h:form>
                <input type="hidden" id="idFunc" name="idFunc"
                    value="#{param['id']}" />
                <div class="senha">
                    <div class="row2">
                        <p:outputLabel class="nova_senha" value="Crie uma nova senha" />
                        <br /> <br />
                    </div>
                    <div class="row_center">
                        <div class="row3">
                            <p:outputLabel class="label_senha" value="Crie sua nova senha: " />
                            <br />
                            <p:password id="passwordInput" class="password" size="35"
                                maxlength="20" value="#{funcionarioBean.novaSenha}"
                                required="true"
                                validatorMessage="Senha válida somente no padrão ipe@1234.">
                                <f:validateRegex
                                    pattern="((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[@#$%])[a-zA-Z0-9@$$%]{8,20})"/>
                            </p:password>
                            * <br /> <br />
                            <p:outputLabel class="label_senha"
                                value="Confirme sua nova senha: " />
                            <br />
                            <p:password id="passwordInput2" class="password" size="35"
                                maxlength="20" value="#{funcionarioBean.novaSenhaConfirma}" />
                            * <br /> <br />
                        </div>
                        <h:commandButton class="botao" value="Confirmar"
                            actionListener="#{funcionarioBean.gerarSenha}"
                            update=":frmLoginGeral" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </h:form>
        </div>
    </ui:define>
```

E essa é a mensagem de erro:

```
 WARNING: org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
    javax.el.ELException: org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:260)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:201)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getJdbcConnectionAccess(AbstractSessionImpl.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.<init>(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.<init>(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1589)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:999)
```

Answer (score 1):

O primeiro problema é que o `.` (ponto) nas sub-expressões exige que sempre haja um caracter antes do que se está tentando verificar. Deveria ser `.*` para dizer que pode ou não haver qualquer número de caracteres antes, como em `(?=.*\\d)`.

O segundo problema é que você está exigindo maiúsculas **e** minúsculas e sua senha não bate. Para exigir qualquer tipo de letra, você teria que trocar `(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])` por `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])`. Alternativamente você teria que testar, por exemplo, com `Ipe@1234`.

O terceiro problema é que o `.` no final permite qualquer caractere na senha, não limitando aos tipos de caracteres já verificados. Isso significa que a senha precisa ter as letras, os números e os caracteres especiais que você exigiu, mas não limita a senha a estes. Para resolver isso, você precisa trocar por `[a-zA-Z0-9@$$%]{6,20}`.

O resultado final seria algo como:

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[@#$%])[a-zA-Z0-9@$$%]{6,20})
```

Testando com o seguinte código:

```
String regex = "((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[@#$%])[a-zA-Z0-9@$$%]{6,20})";
System.out.println("ipe@1234".matches(regex));
System.out.println("ipe@1é234".matches(regex));
System.out.println("i@1".matches(regex));
System.out.println("ipe1234".matches(regex));
System.out.println("@1234".matches(regex));
System.out.println("ipe@".matches(regex));
```

O resultado obtido é verdadeiro (`true`) apenas para o primeiro `println`, como esperado.

Um detalhe que não tenho 100% de certeza é se precisa dar *escape* na barra em `\\d`. A expressão não está numa String do Java e sim num documento `xhtml`, então acho que não precisaria duplicar a barra. Faça o teste com uma ou duas e veja como funciona.

Comment: Bom, fiz o teste com \\d e aparace a mensagem de erro "Senha válida somente no padrão ipe@1234", quando coloquei \d, deu erro 500... segue abaixo:

Comment: Esse é o xhtml que estou usando para fazer a validação editado.